# spark sql dynamic filter condition

Tags: apache-spark, filter, dynamic, apache-spark-sql

How can I construct a boolean filter condition dynamically in spark sql?
Having:

```scala
val d = Seq(1, 2, 3, 5, 6).toDF
d.filter(col("value") === 1 or col("value") === 3).show
```

How can I replicate this dynamically:

```scala
val desiredThings = Seq(1,3)
```

I try to build the filter:

```scala
val myCondition = desiredThings.map(col("value") === _)
d.filter(myCondition).show
```

but fail with:

```scala
overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to (Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column])
```

When executing

```scala
d.filter(myCondition).show
```

Also when experimenting with fold left:

```scala
val myCondition = desiredThings.foldLeft()((result, entry) => result && col(c.columnCounterId) === entry)
```

I have compile errors.

How can I adapt the code to dynamically generate the filter predicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `isin`:

```scala
d.filter(col("value").isin(desiredThings: _*))
```

but if you really want to `foldLeft` you have to provide the base condition:

```scala
d.filter(desiredThings.foldLeft(lit(false))(
  (acc, x) => (acc || col("value") === (x)))
)
```

Alternatively, to use with `filter` or where, you can generate a SQL expression using:

```scala
val filterExpr = desiredThings.map( v => s"value = $v").mkString(" or ")
```

And then use it like

```scala
d.filter(filterExpr).show
// or
d.where(filterExpr).show

//+-----+
//|value|
//+-----+
//|    1|
//|    3|
//+-----+
```